# Dig further into json

Tags: json, wordpress

Im taking my first steps in json.

There is a huge database where you can query all kinds of statistics regarding my country. Like population
http://px.hagstofa.is/pxen/pxweb/en

Now, if you surf the link above to say population you end up here :
http://px.hagstofa.is/pxen/pxweb/en/Ibuar/Ibuar__mannfjoldi__1_yfirlit__arsfjordungstolur/MAN10001.px/?rxid=f4a21b41-fb7a-45dc-9aec-62ae2d3cea5c

If you select some options you get here : 
http://px.hagstofa.is/pxen/pxweb/en/Ibuar/Ibuar__mannfjoldi__1_yfirlit__arsfjordungstolur/MAN10001.px/table/tableViewLayout1/?rxid=f4a21b41-fb7a-45dc-9aec-62ae2d3cea5c

**Click the About table** and then click "**Make this table available in your application**"

Now you see a url for posting to json and the json query......

Ive been trying now for few hours to get any kind of data from this url, but I just cant seem to dig it out.

I tried something like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSON Tutorial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('http://px.hagstofa.is/pxis/api/v1/is/Ibuar/mannfjoldi/2_byggdir/sveitarfelog/MAN02001.px', function(data) {
            console.log(data.variables)
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which gave me the next objects.. But I cannot figure out how to get some statistics.....

for example :
female population in 2015

**Any help is very much needed.**

**EDIT :
Few hours later , im still stuck, but im up to this code now :**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSON Tutorial</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://px.hagstofa.is/pxis/api/v1/is/Ibuar/mannfjoldi/2_byggdir/sveitarfelog/MAN02001.px',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                    $(data.variables).each(function(index, value) {
                    console.log(value.values.Alls + ' test ' + value.values );
                    document.write(value.values[0] + '<br>');
                    });
                }
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Best regards

Comment: Tearing my hair out here.... Im just not able to access the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data.variables` is an array of four objects. Each object contains four properties, among which are `valueTexts` and `values`. So you need a first loop for the first array of four objects, then another loop to find the `valueTexts` / `values` pairs:

```
$.getJSON('http://px.hagstofa.is/pxis/api/v1/is/Ibuar/mannfjoldi/2_byggdir/sveitarfelog/MAN02001.px', function(data) {


  console.log (data.variables);

  for( let i = 0; i < data.variables.length; i++ ){

    console.info( data.variables[i].text );

    for( let k = 0; k < data.variables[i].valueTexts.length; k++ ){
      console.log( data.variables[i].valueTexts[k] + ' ' + data.variables[i].values[k] );
    }

  }


});
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your response... very helpful. But it doesnt give any results..... From my understanding , I need to POST to this query for example : `{
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "Sveitarfélag",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Alls"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "px"
  }
}`

Comment: That's weird, I do get the values - https://www.dropbox.com/s/6blm1loqbqt8q92/Screenshot%202016-08-16%2015.30.12.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Now I don't know what parameters you want and how you'll query it

Comment: valueTexts and values are not the statistics or any kind of results... valueText is the name of the city , and value is the id of the city...... It doesnt give me any results unless I POST to this somehow....

Comment: They say that I need to POST this to the query : `{ "query": [ { "code": "Sveitarfélag", "selection": { "filter": "item", "values": [ "Alls" ] } } ], "response": { "format": "px" } }` to get results

Answer (score 0):

**Below is a working solution for my question :**

There is probably a better way to do this , but I needed a query for the POST, and that gave me results.

Now I just need to make this code spit out the results in csv or xml file.
If anyone has a solution for that , i'd be very thankful.

```
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>


</head>


<script>
        var query = {
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "Sveitarfélag",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Alls"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Aldur",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Alls"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Ár",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "18"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Kyn",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "Alls"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "csv"
  }
};
        query = JSON.stringify(query);
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
          url: "http://px.hagstofa.is/pxis/api/v1/is/Ibuar/mannfjoldi/2_byggdir/sveitarfelog/MAN02001.px",
          data:query,
          success: function(json) {
                document.write(json);
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```